# Generate ID keys in a table with composite keys using Doctrine2 and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have some tables in my DB with composite keys, see the picture below:

[image: Tables with composite keys]

As you can see in this case are `interest` and `klists` which have their own `id` but also has `kuser` as key also. Doctrine docs says that they support almost every uses case in composite keys but every entity with a composite key cannot use an id generator other than “ASSIGNED”. That means the ID fields have to have their values set before you call EntityManager#persist($entity). When I try to define any of the entities related to those tables I got a error because Doctrine doesn't allow to have this:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Id      
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="users" )      
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kuser", referencedColumnName="id")   
   */
   protected $kuser;
```

I know that I can run some code using life-cycle callback but don't know how or where so I need some help here, any can tell me or point me in the right path?

Comment: Why exactly do you need id and kuser to be composite?  AutoIncremented id is already going to be unique.  Why add kuser to the mix?  Just drop the ORM\Id from kuser.

Comment: @Cerad because it need to be a KEY also, I can't remove

Comment: kuser can still be a key.  It will just contain whatever is in kuser.id which is also unique.  Doctrine will take of setting it for you during persisting.  Doctrine will also generate an index on it and take care of cascading.  And if want, you can give it a unique constraint as well.  I think you might have wandered the composite key path a bit too much.  The only time you really see it in Doctrine 2 is in the generated ManyToMany table with no additional attributes.

Comment: @Cerad so table `kuser_has_klists` is in the `ManyToMany`case? I a bit lost at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back to basics.  I'd suggest starting here:  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

```
class KUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

class Interest
{
      /**
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
       */
      protected $id;

      /**      
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\KUser")      
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kuser_id", referencedColumnName="id")   
       */
      protected $kuser;
```

That is all you need to establish a one-way `ManyToOne` relation between Interest and KUser.  If you need it bi-directional then add an `$interests` property to KUser and set the `inversedBy` in Interest.kuser

Make sure you understand the simple relations before proceeding.

Doctrine will auto-generate a `ManyToMany` link table if the link table has no additional properties.  Your KUserHasKLists does have additional attributes.  So you need to make it an entity and then use `ManyToOne` relations to link the the other tables.  And while technically you could probably still use a composite key here, it's much easier to just define an auto-increment primary key.

```
class KUserHasKLists
{
      /**
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
       */
      protected $id;

      /**      
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\KUser")      
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kuser_id", referencedColumnName="id")   
       */
      protected $kuser; 

      /**      
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\KList")      
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="klist_id", referencedColumnName="id")   
       */
      protected $klist;
```

But again, start with a simple relation and make sure you understand what is happening.  Make yourself some functional tests if you are comfortable with phpunit.  If not, make yourself a Symfony Command so you can experiment with this stuff from the command line.